# Android App Launch behavior changed when the app is overwritten while it is running

Tags: android, launch, overwrite, launchmode, relaunch

App launch behavior makes me complicated!
After my app is overwritten to be upgraded while it is running, re-launching behavior is something wrong.

Normally it displays last activity running when I click its icon to resume since it was stopped by home key.
This does as I expected and all activities are called in standard launchMode.

No problem there, but here is the problem.
If I run the same apk to re-install or upgrade it while it is still running then
the app always launches with the activity A that has android.intent.category.LAUNCHER property, does not display last activity B until I kill the app on the task manager and start it again.

I don't get this behavior, and I'm not sure the same issue will be occur when it is upgraded by play store.

The sequence to meet the situation I found is following

1. install App (App should have at least 2 activities, one as a launcher, the other to move)
2. launch app with app icon
3. LAUNCHER activity A displays
4. move to activity B
5. press home key
6. launch the app with app icon again
7. App launches with Activity B <----------------------- check point! It's fine.
8. press home key
9. install the App again with the same version or higher
10. launch app with app icon
11. App launches with Activity A
12. move to activity B
13. press home key
14. launch app with app icon
15. App launches with Activity A <-------------------------- check point! something wrong.
16. kill the app
17. launch app with app icon
18. App launches with Activity A
19. move to activity B
20. press home key
21. launch app with app icon
22. App launches with Activity B <-------------------------- check point! the problem has gone.

I think I got some more issues with me for this thing such as a static objects problem.
so please let me know why this thing happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen always (I mean from step 8 to 15)? or sometimes?

Comment: I also tested this with a simple App containing 2 activities like I mentioned, it happens always if you install the app with apk directly.